# Windows UWP Bluetooh multiple devices showing for single device

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, bluetooth

I am currently working on a C#-UWP app that needs to be able to discovery bluetooth devices (Not BLE) on the network and ones that have been previously connected to/paired.

Im sure anyone who is new to this task will have quickly found the documentation and example are of little help. I have learned more from Stackoverflow questions about peoples experimentations than from the docs and examples, but anyways.

**My main question/problem is this:** After setting up the device watcher to find bluetooth devices I found that I consistently get multiple additions of the same device but having a different bluetooth address (this is a device that was previously paired but not live on the network). After much investigate and brainstorming, we discovered that each device id is actually a pairing of the devices MAC address and the BT receivers MAC address.

The reason I was getting 3 device additions per 1 physical device is because I have connected to that same device with 3 different BT receiver dongles in the past. So my question is, is there anyway to make the device watcher return the device that corresponds to the currently active BT receiver dongle?

Otherwise I will need to find the currently active BT receivers MAC address and filter out the devices that do not have this, because otherwise the user will see 3 identical devices to select and only 1 of them will pass while the other 2 will fail.

While on this subject I would also like to mention that the device properties dont seem to be working. Before creating the watcher, I have a list of properties like this for example:

```
requestedProperties.Add("System.Devices.Aep.DeviceAddress");
requestedProperties.Add("System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected");
requestedProperties.Add("System.Devices.Aep.Bluetooth.Le.IsConnectable");
requestedProperties.Add("System.Devices.Aep.IsPresent");
requestedProperties.Add("System.Devices.Aep.ContainerId");
requestedProperties.Add("System.Devices.Aep.ModelId");
requestedProperties.Add("System.Devices.Aep.Manufacturer");
requestedProperties.Add("System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId");
requestedProperties.Add("System.Devices.Aep.SignalStrength");
```

But when I debug the device that is added, it doesnt have any properties:
[debug info showing no properties for added device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHVdP.png)

I would be useful to have this information.

Thank you for any input or suggestions.

Comment: The following may help you understand the issue better : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//ff536587(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Use Bluetooth API (discovering) instead of DeviceWatcher.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko which bluetooth APIs are you referring to? Could you please post a link? Everywhere ive looked, everyone recommends using device watcher, have seen no other alternatives.

Comment: We use this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bluetooth/using-bluetooth to work with Classic Bluetooth devices.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion but as far as I understand it, this is a C++ API and we are making a C# UWP app. I think its possible to use C++ code in UWP C# but all we want is to be able to see potential devices and we are on a tight deadline. The devices watcher kind works for a simple happy path scenario but sure seems untrustworthy. Maybe if we have some time left in the future we might come back and use this API.

Comment: As you mentioned, I think that you could filter these devices through DeviceId. Since these displayed device have same [Device.Name]( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice.name?view=winrt-19041) and different DeviceId, you could find the specified device whose DeviceId corresponds to the current BT receiver based on this feature. Then you could remove two device that don’t match and bind the filtered collection to the dropdown list.

Comment: Yes, we are going with this solution for now even thought it would probably be more efficient for the device watcher to not give these devices, ive updated my question to include the work around.

Comment: Maybe you could separate your question and workaround, then post your solution as an answer. So that you could [mark your own answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), which will help the others that face the same question and promote the development of this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I found a quick solution that overcomes this problem (although i did find a lot more problems with the device watcher but that is probably a topic for another question).

For now I simply get the current BT adaptors MAC address and then check each incoming device if it has this MAC address in its pair. If it does not that means the device is paired with an old/unused BT adaptor.

```
/*  NOTE:
Windows allows only 1 BT adapter to be active on 1 machine at a time
Therefore this function will either return the active dongle or a null if 
there is no BT adapter on the machine or its disabled.
*/
BluetoothAdapter BTAdaptor = await BluetoothAdapter.GetDefaultAsync();

if (BTAdaptor == null)
{
   // Log error
   // return
}

//
// Code block to check if the BT adaptor can support the BT tech stack you are interested in.
//

// Format into hex with 12 characters (12 being the number of characters for MAC address)
string tempMac = BTAdaptor.BluetoothAddress.ToString("X12").ToLower();

// Pattern for MAC address.
string pattern = "(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})";
string replace = "$1:$2:$3:$4:$5:$6";

m_strBTAdapterMAC = Regex.Replace(tempMac, pattern, replace);
```

Then when the device is added/updated/removed by the watcher event, check it:

```
// If device is not paired with the currently used BT adapter. 
if (deviceInfo.Id.Contains(m_strBTAdapterMAC) == false)
{
     // Device paired with old dongle, dont want to show the user.
     return;
}
```

If anyone ever figures out how to make the device watcher just not give old devices, please let me know, its probably a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question with the system properties;

I had the same issue. Even when debugging and setting 'Enable native code debugging' on the assembly. But then I realized simply using for example;

```
var addressStr = e.Properties["System.Devices.Aep.DeviceAddress"].ToString()
```

This will get you the property. It will fail if you don't request the property from the watcher (which it looks like you are already doing) i.e.

```
requestedProperties.Add("System.Devices.Aep.DeviceAddress");
```